# Safari requests from the address bar (Preload Top hit in the background)

Tags: javascript, ruby-on-rails, safari, request

I have a Rails app where I'm doing some internal actions according to query strings in the browser.

For example, the user go to `example.com?do=something`.
Rails are checking the params, do some DB manipulations, and redirect to `example.com`.

It works fine in most of the browsers except desktop Safari. Safari has a setting called "Preload Top hit in the background" which making requests in the background. 
It leads to the behavior of doing more actions needed on the backend.

I tried to trace these requests by some characteristics but it seems they are the same as for regular page visits.

Has anyone faced this issue and know how I can cut off these requests?
I can use the JS here as well but not sure how it could help.

Answer (score 0):

Your best option is just to handle the use case.

Its just functionality from Safari that can be disabled by a user but you shouldn't try to stop the request from sending.

Also most people would not type a URL with a `GET` param in it anyways so it probably wont happen often.